# How to set a start number ID for Work Items on a new System Center Service Manager 2019 installation?

Tags: system-center

We are installing a new instance of System Center Service Manager (SCSM) 2019 and we have the version 2012 that we will be maintained for legacy.

It is desirable that the identification number of Work Items on both SCSM doesn't conflict.

So, we need to set a start number identification for the Work Items on the new installation, like 400,000 (SR400000).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I founded a solution [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/system-center-blog/top-secret-trick-how-to-change-the-auto-incrementing-value-range/ba-p/342132).

It's summarized below.

Basicaly, there is this table in the ServiceManager database called the `AutoIncrementAvailableRange` table.  This value stores the next available number for a particular class property.

First you need to know which row represents the property you want to update.  If you just run this:

```
select
    MT.TypeName,
    MT.ManagedTypeId,
    MTP.ManagedTypePropertyName,
    MTP.ManagedTypePropertyID,
    AIAR.FirstAvailableValue
from ManagedType as MT, 
    ManagedTypeProperty as MTP, 
    AutoIncrementAvailableRange as AIAR
where MT.ManagedTypeId = AIAR.ManagedTypeId 
    and MTP.ManagedTypePropertyId = AIAR.ManagedTypePropertyId
```

[image]

So – now let’s say we want to adjust the WorkItem ID to start at 10000.  We would just run a query like this:

```
update AutoIncrementAvailableRange
set FirstAvailableValue = 10000
where ManagedTypeId = 'F59821E2-0364-ED2C-19E3-752EFBB1ECE9' 
and ManagedTypePropertyId = '28B1C58F-AEFA-A449-7496-4805186BD94F'
```

It seens to work.

[image]

Comment: awesome! saved my day. Thanks